# map with key which is combination of multiple values in c++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, set

I want a map in c++, in which its key is combination of multiple values. I can use both stl and boost also.

Key values can be string/integers something like below

```
typedef value_type int;
typedef key(string, template(string,int), template(string,int)) key_type;
typedef map(key_type, value_type) map_type;

map_type map_variable;
map_variable.insert(key_type("keyStrning1", 1, "keyString2"), 4);
map_variable.insert(key_type("keyStrning3", 1, "keyString2"), 5);
```

Now this map will contain two entries and i shall be able to find it like below:

```
map_variable.find(key_type("keyStrning3", 1, "keyString2")).
```

I can use nested maps , but i want to know is there any convenient solution for this using either boost or c++ stl.

Comment: You can have a class with these members as the key.

Comment: So you want the key to be a structure, or possibly a tupple? For [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) all you really need to do is implement the comparison operators.

Comment: the second and third key can be either a string or an integer? so `key_type("ss", 1, "333")` is a valid key and `key_type("ss", "aa", 1)`  should be valid as well.

Comment: yes @giuseppe-pes, `key_type("ss", 1, "333")` and `key_type("ss", "aa", 1)` are both valid key

Comment: Then `std::variant` is the way to go..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `boost::variant` (or `std::variant` when *C++17* will be ready).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

typedef int ValueType;
typedef boost::variant<std::string, int> StrOrInt;
typedef std::tuple<std::string, StrOrInt, StrOrInt> KeyType;
typedef std::map<KeyType, ValueType> MapType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MapType amap;
  amap.insert(std::make_pair(
                std::make_tuple("string1", "string2", 3),  <--- key
                4));  // <--- value

  auto finder = amap.find(std::make_tuple("string1", "string2", 3));

  std::cout << finder->second << '\n';  // <--- prints 4

  return 0;
}
```